# Showing $\varphi_i : \mathbb P^n - Z(x_i) \to \mathbb A^n$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

From Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* Chapter 1 section 2:

Here $U_i = \mathbb P^n - Z(x_i)$, and $\varphi_i(a_0, \dots, a_n)= (a_1/a_i, \dots, a_n/a_i)$ with $a_i/a_i$ omitted.

It doesn't seem very straightforward checking the highlighted part.

Let $\varphi_i(a_0, \dots, a_n)= (a_1/a_0, \dots, a_n/a_0) \in \varphi(Y)$.

We want to show that $(a_1/a_0, \dots, a_n/a_0) \in Z(T')$.

Let $f \in T'$. Then $f=\alpha(g(x_0, \dots, x_n))=g(1, x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

Then $g(1, a_1/a_0, \dots, a_n/a_0) = 1/a_0^{deg(g)} g(a_0^{deg(g)}, a_1, \dots, a_n)$.

Why should this be $0$?

---

> [image]
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Let us show that $\varphi(Y)\subset Z(T')$. Let $p=[a_0:\ldots:a_n]$ be a point in $Y$ and let $f\in T$. Then by definition $f(a_0,\ldots,a_n)=0$. Since $f$ is homogeneous and $a_0\neq0$ it follows that

$$f(1,\frac{a_1}{a_0},\ldots,\frac{a_n}{a_0})=0\,.$$

But this is precisely saying that $\alpha(f)(\varphi(p))=0$, that is, $\varphi(p)\in Z(T')$.

The reverse inclusion $Z(T')\subset \varphi(Y)$ should also be easy and should follow by a similar analysis.